# splunk dashboard to include the time rage that will populate into the pdf file

Tags: pdf, splunk, timepicker, splunk-dashboard

I have a splunk dashboard that returns results based on a time picker with a start and end time frame
I would like to have that time range in the dashboard so that the PDF generated it shows the time frame.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a `<panel>` with `<html>` that displays the `$date.earliest$` and `$date.latest$` values:

```
<row>
  <panel>
    <html>
     <h1>Date Range : $date.earliest$ - $date.latest$ </h1>
   </html>
  </panel>
</row>
```

You may want to format the values to reflect the actual dateTime values. You can evaluate fields with formatted dateTime values:

```
<input type="time" token="date" searchWhenChanged="true">
  <label>date</label>
  <default>
    <earliest>-40m@m</earliest>
    <latest>now</latest>
  </default>
  <change>
    <eval token="timelabel_earliest">if(isnum($date.earliest$), strftime($date.earliest$,"%m/%d/%Y %H:%M"), strftime(relative_time(now(), $date.earliest$),"%m/%d/%Y %H:%M") )</eval>
    <eval token="timelabel_latest">if(isnum($date.latest$), strftime($date.latest$,"%m/%d/%Y %H:%M"), strftime(relative_time(now(), $date.latest$), "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M") )</eval>
  </change>
</input>
```

And then use the fields with the formatted values:

```
<row>
  <panel>
    <html>
      <h1>$AppEnv$ : $timelabel_earliest$ - $timelabel_latest$ </h1>
    </html>
  </panel>
</row>
```

Below is a complete example of a dashboard demonstrating how to display both the time picker value and formatted:

```
<form>
  <label>Display Time Picker</label>
  <fieldset submitButton="false">
    <input type="time" token="field1">
      <label></label>
      <default>
        <earliest>-24h@h</earliest>
        <latest>now</latest>
      </default>
       <change>
         <eval token="timelabel_earliest">if(isnum($field1.earliest$), strftime($field1.earliest$,"%m/%d/%Y %H:%M"), strftime(relative_time(now(), $field1.earliest$),"%m/%d/%Y %H:%M") )</eval>
         <eval token="timelabel_latest">if(isnum($field1.latest$), strftime($field1.latest$,"%m/%d/%Y %H:%M"), strftime(relative_time(now(), $field1.latest$), "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M") )</eval>
      </change>
    </input>
  </fieldset>
  <row>
  <panel>
    <html>
     <h1>Date Range: $field1.earliest$ - $field1.latest$ </h1>
     <h1>Date Range formatted: $timelabel_earliest$ - $timelabel_latest$ </h1>
   </html>
  </panel>
</row>
</form>
```

Which renders like this:
[image: Example dateTime labels]

Comment: so in my dashboard I add a panel, then I go into edit source and add that section for the new panel? Then when I select a time range it will display in that panel and in the pdf file?

Comment: I'm not following this. I have a time picker on my dashboard where I between (start - end) time range. My dashboard populates. My dashboard has 6 panels. I want to see that time in a panel on my dashboard. If I add a panel it wants a search string. My time picker has the token Time and it is shared to all panels. When ever I add any of this nothing populates with that time? - Thank You

Comment: It might be helpful if you posted some of your dashboard source. What I posted works for me on my dashboards.

Comment: Here is the time picker source and one Panel

Comment: Not really enough space I'm just not following your reply? I have a dashboard with a time picker that I use between (start / end ) all the panels populate If I go into source I see everything fine but where do I put this code or when I say add panel what type of panel since it needs a search string. I just need to show in the dashboard the time used in the picker? thank you

Comment: <input type="Time" token="Time" searchWhenChanged="true">
  <label>Time</label>
  <change>
    <eval token="timelabel_earliest">if(isnum($Time.earliest$), strftime($Time.earliest$,"%m/%d/%Y %H:%M"), strftime(relative_time(now(), $Time.earliest$),"%m/%d/%Y %H:%M") )</eval>
    <eval token="timelabel_latest">if(isnum($Time.latest$), strftime($Time.latest$,"%m/%d/%Y %H:%M"), strftime(relative_time(now(), $Time.latest$), "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M") )</eval>
  </change>
</input>
  <row>
  <panel>
    <html>
     <h1>Time Range : $Time.earliest$ - $Time.latest$ </h1>
   </html>
  </panel>
</row>

Comment: I get an error with the <input type="time" token="date" searchWhenChanged="true"> can't be here, it is just after the time picker section at the top

Comment: I meant to update the question with more code from your dashboard. Put the row and panel outside of the fieldset. Inputs are separate from display. I have updated my answer with a more complete generic dashboard solution demonstrating.

Comment: almost perfect. It gets the start time but the end time is the same as the start

Comment: almost perfect. It gets the start time but the end time is the same as the start it also removed my submit button and my text input field . my dashboard has a time picket roken - time text box token =myID and a submit button. when I add this it populated only the start time and the others were gone

Comment: Ah, that's my fault. When putting together the minimal example, the date field is `field1` but my dashboard was `date`. So, need to adjust the eval expressions to use `field1` (or rename the field). I'll update my example.

Comment: <form>
  <label>Date Range for this alert</label>
  <fieldset submitButton="true" autoRun="false">
    <input type="time" token="time">
      <label>time</label>
      <default>
        <earliest>-24h@h</earliest>
        <latest>now</latest>
      </default>
    </input>
    <input type="text" token="merchID">
      <label>Merchant ID</label>
    </input>
  </fieldset> this is what I have

Comment: okay, so if your field `token="time"` then anywhere that you reference that field, use `$time`. My last example has a field called `field1` so is using `$field1.earliest$`. You would use `$date.earliest$`

Comment: awesome - Thank you so much. It looks good!

Comment: I thought so but does not refresh with new time change in the picker